# How to determine the docusign recipient action taken on document

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Remote Signing with the DocuSign api, but I want to know how to determine what action the recipient took (i.e. they signed, declined to sign, viewed, etc). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want the status of the envelopes you sent?

Best technique is to create a webhook and have DocuSign call your server when the envelope's status changes.

You can create DocuSign notification message subscriptions at either the account level or at the individual envelope level.

See this [blog entry](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhooks-dont-poll-us-well-call/) for more info. Ask additional questions on StackOverflow if you have any difficulties.